# Overlapping interval of a Poisson arrival process

Tags: self-study, joint-distribution, poisson-process

Calls arrives according to a Poisson arrival process with rate lambda = 15. Find E(N(2,4]N(3,5])

My thoughts: E(N(2,4]) = E(N(3,5]) = lambda * t = 15 * 2 = 30 However, I cannot figure out the next step, since (2,4] and (3,5] are NOT non-overlapping, so they are NOT independent and I cannot get the resulting expectation by simply multiplying them.

I'm really stuck in this. Can someone please explain this problem? Many thanks.

Comment: Hint: Can you split it into parts that are independent and perfectly dependent?

Comment: @Glen_b I seem to get you. Divide it into (2,3], (3,4], (4,5] and then they are all independent then I can just multiply and add them one by one. Is this correct?

Comment: They aren't all independent. Let $X_{(i,j]}$ be the count in $(i,j]$. Then your expectation can be written as the expectation of the product of two sums ... most terms in the expansion are independent, but not all of them. Poor notation is making your life harder here.